# Get rid of borders around p:selectManyCheckBox

Tags: css, primefaces

I am trying to implement following look: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectManyCheckbox.jsf

Notice there is no css-borders around the component at the PrimeFaces showcase site.

```
 <h:outputText value="Horizontal: " />  
 <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{formBean.selectedOptions}">  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="Option 2" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="Option 3" />  
 </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

However, I got unwanted borders around the component in my implementation. I have tried to add style="border-style: none;" i.e.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{formBean.selectedOptions}" style="border-style: none;">
```

without any result. I have a default.css file according to:

```
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 80% !important;
}
```

I do not think that the css resource will have any affect on this issue, but I might be wrong.

I can't see any difference in look between differnet browsers.

Can you please tell me why I got borders and how I can get rid of them, only at this specific component?

Best regards

Comment: Since you've not provided any of your own code, it's hard to help you. But a guess would be that border:0; would help. And please don't place it inline (on the element) but in a class.

Comment: What browser and browser version number are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borders? Primefaces' `p:selectManyCheckbox` has no borders by default.

Anyhow, if you want to override any style rule you can use `!important`.

This should remove any border:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{formBean.selectedOptions}" style="border-style: none !important;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with havning no borders. I tried removing all my css but I still got borders. Might be theme specific.

I had to use the following:

```
.noBorder tr,.noBorder td {
    border: none !important;
}



<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{formBean.selectedOptions}" styleClass="noBorder">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1" />
                    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```